# Прописные буквы в новогоднем поздравлении

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Во первЫх строках своего вопроса хочу поздравить всех с наступающим Новым годом.)) А теперь вопрос: когда пишешь поздравления, а именно, такой текст: "Желаю тебе в новом году...". И вот тут-то я споткнулся: в данном случае "в новом году" должно писаться с прописной или строчной буквы?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Новый год - это название праздника, составное имя собственное, первое слово пишется с прописной буквы. Желаю в новом году - это обычное словосочетание, а то получится: "желаю (в празднике)".

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Всё-таки строчная буква смотрится не очень празднично. Тогда есть выход: пишем "Желаю в Новом году", а выбор прописной буквы объясняем не названием праздника, а особой ЗНАЧИМОСТЬЮ И ТОРЖЕСТВЕННОСТЬЮ слова.